# Setting connection timeout in RestEASY

Tags: resteasy

JBoss tells us

http://docs.jboss.org/seam/3/rest/latest/reference/en-US/html/rest.client.html

that to set the timeout for a RestEASY ClientRequest we must create a custom ClientExecutor, then call deprecated static methods on ConnManagerParams.  This seems rather hokey.  Is there a better way?  This is RestEASY 2.3.6.

Comment: I have the same issue, did you find an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a clean working solution :-)

```
@Singleton
public class RestEasyConfig {

    @Inject
    @MyConfig
    private Integer httpClientMaxConnectionsPerRoute;

    @Inject
    @MyConfig
    private Integer httpClientTimeoutMillis;

    @Inject
    @MyConfig
    private Integer httpClientMaxTotalConnections;

    @Produces
    private ClientExecutor clientExecutor;

    @PostConstruct
    public void createExecutor() {
        final BasicHttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, this.httpClientTimeoutMillis);

        final SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry();
        schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("http", 80, PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory()));

        final ThreadSafeClientConnManager connManager = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(schemeRegistry);
        connManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(this.httpClientMaxConnectionsPerRoute);
        connManager.setMaxTotal(this.httpClientMaxTotalConnections);

        final HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(connManager, params);

        this.clientExecutor = new ApacheHttpClient4Executor(httpClient);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

With RestEASY 3.12.1.Final, as explained by [redhat website](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.3/html-single/developing_web_services_applications/index), I did it this way:

```
    private Client clientBuilder() {
        return new ResteasyClientBuilder()
            .connectTimeout(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build()
            .register(ClientRestLoggingFilter.class)
            .register(ObjectMapperContextResolver.class);
    }
```